# Type hinting in long arrays does not improve performance of aget

Tags: performance, clojure

Here is the code:

```
(time
  (dorun 1000000
         (repeatedly #(let [a (long-array (range 10))]
                       (aget a 7)))))
(time
  (dorun 1000000
         (repeatedly #(let [^longs a (long-array (range 10))]
                       (aget a 7)))))
```

Comment: Type hinting is relevant for interop situations where the compiler couldn't otherwise infer a type. Unless setting `*warn-on-reflection*` to true would generate a warning on a given piece of code, hinting generally won't help.

Answer (score 4):

The call to `long-array` is inlined by the Clojure compiler into a call to the Java method `clojure.lang.Numbers/long_array`, which has a return type of `long[]`. Thus, the compiler is already able to infer the type of `a` and type-hinting gives you no benefit here.

Compare this to:

```
(time
  (dorun 1000000
         (repeatedly #(let [a (or (long-array (range 10))
                                  (int-array (range 10)))]
                       (aget a 7)))))
```

Here, the compiler is unable to infer the type of `a` since it can't predict which branch of the `or` will return, so you should see a significant performance hit compared to your example code.